# how to get list of service buses in a subscription or RG

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to use

```
var adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(
```

to fetch some topics related data.

I see that ServiceBusAdministrationClient can be used for one SB. Is there a way to get a list of SBs in an Azure subscription or Resource Group so I can loop on it and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK you would want to use is [`Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.servicebus?view=azure-dotnet).

To list Namespaces in a Subscription, the method you will need to use is [`NamespacesOperationsExtensions.ListAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.namespacesoperationsextensions.listasync?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-management-servicebus-namespacesoperationsextensions-listasync(microsoft-azure-management-servicebus-inamespacesoperations-system-threading-cancellationtoken)).

Similarly to list Namespaces in a Resource Group, the method you will need to use is [`NamespacesOperationsExtensions.ListByResourceGroupAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.namespacesoperationsextensions.listbyresourcegroupasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Your code would be something like (untested though):

```
var credentials = new DefaultAzureCredentials();

using (ServiceBusManagementClient client = new ServiceBusManagementClient(credentials))
{
    client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    var namespaces = client.Namespaces.ListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Note there is a new management library available now - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.ServiceBus

Comment: @JoshLove - Thanks. For some reason I was not able to find this in Microsoft documentation. Even their documentation talks about the old SDK - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-bus?view=azure-dotnet#management-library.

Comment: i am having an issue that ServiceBusManagementClient takes in Rest.ServiceClientCredentials and  the other issue is that an instance of namespace doesnt seems to have a function to return the list of ServiceBusses